# Why does the installer view my partitioned hard drive as one non-partitioned disk?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, installation

I try to install 11.10 on my Asus U30JC laptop. I have 3 partitions. 2 for windows and another Ext3 partition for Ubuntu. I try to install Ubuntu with my USB flash memory. The problem is when you should select the installation partition, it just shows my HDD as a single 500 Gigabyte Unallocated partition. Anyone has any idea what the problem may be?

```
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   137129983    68461568    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       137130901   210354175    36611637+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       210355173   976768064   383206446    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       137134080   149716991     6291456   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       149719040   210354175    30317568   83  Linux
```

Comment: [    6.185959] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/465 GiB)
[    6.186035] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    6.186047] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    6.186072] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    6.246528]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 < sda5 sda6 sda7 >
[    6.247081] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    8.117459] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 7831552 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 GB/3.73 GiB)
[    8.118250] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    8.118256] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense:43 00 00 00

Comment: [    8.119122] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[    8.119127] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.122932] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[    8.122937] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.123573]  sdb: sdb1
[    8.126544] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[    8.126549] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    8.126554] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[    9.055432] EXT3-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode

Comment: [   23.431123] Adding 6291452k swap on /dev/sda6.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:6291452k 
[  132.924466] EXT3-fs (sda7): using internal journal
[  132.924474] EXT3-fs (sda7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode

Comment: This shows "sda" as a 500GB HDD, but I see six partitions: sda1, sda2, sda3, sda5, sda6, and sda7 - not the three you mentioned initially.  Send the output of this command `fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Comment: Can you add info by editing the original question instead of posing comments.

Comment: /dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   137129983    68461568    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       137130901   210354175    36611637+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       210355173   976768064   383206446    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       137134080   149716991     6291456   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7       149719040   210354175    30317568   83  Linux

Comment: @mikewhatver - When I hover over my past posts, I only have the (X) (delete this comment) option.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @dan_linder If you wait too long after posting a comment, you lose the ability to edit it. You can delete them and make new comments to replace them, however.

Comment: @dan_linder or better yet just edit your question and add the information there, it will make it easier to see the information up front.

Comment: Please run `sudo fdisk -lu /dev/sda` again and add the missing first line that shows the total size of the drive.

Comment: Boot into the live environment and run dmesg | grep sd[abcd], then post the output here.

Comment: Interesting - your system shows it already has the partitions created for Linux (/dev/sda7).  Do you mind blowing it away, then installing fresh to that?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you chose the "don't overwrite any existing filesystems" option when you're starting the install?  (I can't remember the exact name for that option...)

If the Linux partition (/dev/sda6 and /dev/sda7) is not needed, you could try deleting that partition and see if the installer sees the "free" space.  Then the installer should see the free space and let you install there.